# Postgresql: comparing arrays results in "malformed array literal" error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, postgresql, rails-activerecord

I have a Rails app and a column that contains an array like `["manager", "engineer"]` etc. and a where statement like this:

```
where("? = ANY roles", query)
```

which works find if I pass a single value for query.  I want to be able to pass multiple values.  I did some Googling and an simple solution was found:

```
where("? && roles", query )
```

except that if I pass something in like `"['admin', 'guest']"` I get this error:

```
PG::InvalidTextRepresentation: ERROR:  malformed array literal: "['admin', 'guest']"
LINE 1: ....                                       $1 AND ('[''admin'...
                                                             ^
DETAIL:  "[" must introduce explicitly-specified array dimensions.
```

I suspect that there is some weird quote escaping issue but I can't figure it out.  Those error messages results in a bunch of JSON Q&As but nothing that jumps out with a solution.

**UPDATE**

I always seem to find a clue after posting a question - I tried:

```
where("'{guest, admin}'::text[] && roles", query )
```

and it works - I still don't really know why but it does.  Now I can't see how to get the `?` back in there now so I can search on it.

**UPDATE 2**

I took the first answer below and did a bit of refactoring to get what I think is a simple elegant solution:

```
where("'{#{roles}}'::text[] && roles")
```

This way I can pass a simple text string to my application helper that this where clause sits.  It handles single and multiple queries.

Comment: Would you be able to show what you have stored in the variable roles in update 2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're almost always better off using the *array constructor* syntax for arrays. From the [fine manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-ARRAY-CONSTRUCTORS):

> **4.2.12. Array Constructors**
>
> An array constructor is an expression that builds an array value using values for its member elements. A simple array constructor consists of the key word `ARRAY`, a left square bracket `[`, a list of expressions (separated by commas) for the array element values, and finally a right square bracket `]`. For example:
>
> ```
> SELECT ARRAY[1,2,3+4];
>   array
> ---------
>  {1,2,7}
> (1 row)
> ```

ActiveRecord will expand an array value for a placeholder into a comma delimited list and that's exactly what the `array[...]` syntax wants between the brackets. So you'd say:

```
where('array[?] && roles', query)
```

This even does the right thing if `query` is a single value.

---

As far as your **UPDATE** goes, this:

```
'{guest, admin}'::text[]
```

is a string literal (`'{guest, admin}'`) followed by a type cast (`::`) to an array-of-text (`text[]`). The `'{...}'` syntax inside the string is another form of an array that is easy to read but a hassle to properly build; the [fine manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/arrays.html#ARRAYS-INPUT) also covers this form:

> **8.15.2. Array Value Input**
>
> To write an array value as a literal constant, enclose the element values within curly braces and separate them by commas.

I use the `array[...]` version exclusively because it is easier to work with and more explicit as to what type the array elements are.

Comment: Please don't use string interpolation to build SQL. `roles` could contain all sorts of unpleasant things that can break your "elegant" solution.

Comment: I get that but I have to manual the input in my views and you can't manipulate it via the params etc. Any suggestion on a better way to do this?

Comment: I don't understand this: "I have to manual the input in my views and you can't manipulate it via the params". Why does it have to be a comma-delimited string and why can't you manipulate it?

Comment: I will expand my question when I get back to my computer. What I am trying to say is that the 'roles' being feed into this search is not editable etc from the end user. It's a hard coded call in my view i.e. myhelper_function("manager, admin"). The risk is low that I break something but after seeing the comments I agree that should still try to sanitize my input and look to catch the double quotes etc.

Comment: You could say `myhelper_function(%w[manager admin])`,  `myhelper_function('manager', 'admin')`, or `myhelper_function(*%w[manager admin])` instead. Taking an unnecessary shortcut is false-laziness.

Answer (score 0):

#### Edit

***DO NOT do what this answer suggests since it is dangerous and fragile. It was one of those things I really did not think through and regret posting in public***

You want your array literal to be formatted like `'{"admin", "guest"}'`

#### Response to edited OP

```
query_terms = ["admin", "guest"]
query = "{#{ query_terms.map {|term| %Q("#{ term }") }.join(",") }}"
where("? && roles",  query)
```

Comment: What happens if one of the `query_terms` contains a double quote?

Comment: @muistooshort Then I hope you sanitized your input! Answer removed since it was horrible and should not be used.