# Rails PostgreSQL checking an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, postgresql

I have looked heavily into replicating the answer provided here [Postgresql: comparing arrays results in "malformed array literal" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34735673/postgresql-comparing-arrays-results-in-malformed-array-literal-error)
However I still receive an error.

I have two tables Locations, and Customers.
Locations belongs to customers

```
addresses = ["1 Mullberry St", "24 Western Ave", "923 Shetland Dr"]    

Customer.joins(:location)
  .where("'#{addresses}'::text[] && locations.street1")
  .pluck(:email)
```

Below is the SQL and the error that I receive

```
SELECT "customers"."email"
  FROM "customers"
    INNER JOIN "locations" ON "locations"."customer_id" = "customers"."id"
      WHERE ('{'1 Mullberry St', '24 Western Ave', '923 Shetland 
Dr'}'::text[] && locations.street1)

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "1"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to get the emails from customers which have their location.street1 in that list?

If that's the case then the SQL you want to end up with is more like:

```
SELECT "customers"."email"
FROM "customers" INNER JOIN "locations" ON "locations"."customer_id" = "customers"."id"
WHERE locations.street1 IN ('1 Mullberry St', '24 Western Ave', '923 Shetland Dr')
```

To do that in Rails should be as simple as:

```
Customer.joins(:location)
  .where("locations.street1" => addresses)
  .pluck(:email)
```

Comment: Thank you, I did not realize you could use location.DOT. in that syntax. I switched to the colon rather than the hash rocket.